# MIPS: Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400014

Tags: assembly, mips

Alright, so I've started writing MIPS code to multiply two arrays. I wanted to put what I had so far into QtSpim to see if values would change as I was expecting them to.

However, when I try to load my file into QtSpim I am getting this error:
`Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400014`

Do you see where I'm going wrong, or have any good ideas for debugging? I'm not sure what or where the problem is.

Thanks.

***EDIT***: This works:

```
main:
    la      $a2, array1
    la      $a3, array2
    li  $a1, 5
    li  $v0, 1
    add     $a0, $a1, $0
    syscall

    lw  $a0, 0($a2)
    syscall

    lw  $a0, 0($a3)
    syscall

    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
.data
array1: .word 10, 10, 10, 10, 5
array2: .word -10, -10, 10, 10, 5
```

Full code:

```
.data
array1: .word 10, 10, 10, 10, 5
array2: .word -10, -10, 10, 10, 5

main:

li $a2, 5
addiu $15, $a2, 1
la $a0, array1
la $a1, array2
j MAC

MAC:

addiu $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, 4($sp)
li $v1, 0
li $s0, 0

loopInMAC:

beq $s0, $15, main2
j mult1
add $v1, $v1, $v0
addiu $s0, $s0, 1
j loopInMAC

mult1:

lw $s1, 0($a0)
lw $s2, 0($a1)
slt $s3, $s1, 0
slt $s4, $s2, 0
addiu $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra 0($sp)
bne $s3, 1, skip1
sub $s1, $0, $s1

skip1:

bne $s4, 1, skip2
sub $s2, $0, $s2

skip2:

li $v0, 0

loopInMult:

beq $s1, $0, skip3
andi $t0, $s1, 1
beq $t0, $0, skipAdd
add $v0, $v0, $s2

skipAdd:

sll $s2, $s2, 1
srl $s1, $s1, 1
j loopInMult

skip3:

beq $s1, $s2, equalSign
sub $v0, $0, $v0

equalSign:
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't place code in the `.data` section. You should start the `.text` (code) section before `main:`, i.e:

```
.text
main:
```

Also, you've got a couple of instructions placed before `main:` that currently will never be executed. I suspect that those are meant to be placed after `main:`

Comment: No, I can't place it before the main. It needs the main to be on the first line, unless I create a globl. main, which is what my teacher ended up telling me last night. However he said the safest bet is to simply place the .data at the end of the file, so that I never get an error with my code

Comment: _"I can't place it before the main. It needs the main to be on the first line"_  Umm, yes you can, and, no it doesn't. `.text` doesn't generate any code/data. It just tells the assembler that you want the code and data that follows to be placed in the `.text` section.